# Conditional dependency injection via middleware in Blazor.Server

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is it possible to have 2 different implementations of a service and inject a specific implementation into a component based on the props passed to it?

I have tried to find a solution and all I could find is pulling the desired service out of the services provider in the constructor which I don't want to do. I have done something similar in an API Controller which essentially would intercept the request before the service layer was injected and inject the correct service implementation depending on the request parameters.

Edit:

Essentially during startup I want to be able to inject 2 implementations of the same interface service.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService,EmployeeServiceA>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService,EmployeeServiceB>();
```

Then in my component I would do something like:

```
@inject IEmployeeService _employeeService;
```

With the actual implementation being injected into the component being decided based off of parameters being sent into the component which would be intercepted by middle wear.

Comment: You could consider a factory arrangement similar to IHttpClientFactory and store the services by a key/name.

Comment: @BrianParker I thought about doing that also, but I would still have the issue of not being able to intercept parameters between passing of parameters. I ended up just creating a composite service and tried to move some type checking as far back as I could. The main point of this was moving some type checking away from the UI layer. I couldn't do it in the server services layer due to it being relatively UI specific, so I just had to settle on moving it back a few layers on the UI services side. I don't love it, but I think most would accept it as a good compromise.

Comment: Keyed DI services were introduced by Microsoft after the accepted answer was posted and might provide a solution for some developers reading this question.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8#keyed-di-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually get the correct service from the ServiceProvider by injecting the IServiceProvider and calling `GetService` on the provider.

Note: This is not recommended for normal component injection because you need to be careful about when you use the service: you may try and access it before you have initialized it.  In the example below it's not available in `OnInitialized`.

Here's an example for a simple notification service.

An interface:

```
public interface INotificationService
{
    public event EventHandler? Changed;
    public void NotifyChanged(object? sender);
}
```

Two classes:

```
public class WeatherForecastNotificationService
    : INotificationService
{
    public event EventHandler? Changed;
    public void NotifyChanged(object? sender)
        => this.Changed?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

```
public class WeatherReportNotificationService
    : INotificationService
{
    public event EventHandler? Changed;

    public void NotifyChanged(object? sender)
        => this.Changed?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Registered as (scoped) services:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<WeatherForecastNotificationService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<WeatherReportNotificationService>();
```

A component to get the services - ServiceTestComponent.razor:

```
@inject IServiceProvider serviceProvider

<div class="bg-info p-2 m-2">
    <h3>ServiceTestComponent</h3>
    <div class="p-3">
        Type: @message
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public object? Record { get; set; }

    private INotificationService notificationService = default!;
    private string message = string.Empty;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (this.Record is WeatherForecast)
        {
            var service = serviceProvider.GetService<WeatherForecastNotificationService>();
            if (service is not null)
                notificationService = service as INotificationService;
        }
        else
        {
            var service = serviceProvider.GetService<WeatherReportNotificationService>();
            if (service is not null)
                notificationService = service as INotificationService;
        }

        // simple bit of code to demo what actual service we have
        if (notificationService is not null)
            message = notificationService.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

And a test page:

```
@page "/"
@page "/Index"

<h1>Hello</h1>
<ServiceTestComponent Record=this.record />
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=ChangeType>Change Type</button>
</div>
@code
{
    private object record = new WeatherForecast();

    private void ChangeType()
    {
        if (record is WeatherForecast)
            record = new WeatherReport();

        else
            record = new WeatherForecast();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is essentially the end result that I came up with as an initial workaround if I couldn't implement middle wear to do it for me. I don't like having type checking in the component itself so I'll probably try to abstract it away from the component and have a composite service of some sort. Just wish I could have a middleware layer intercept the parameters before initializing the component, but it doesn't look like it's possible. Thanks for your explanation.